# Distances in a compact metric space

Tags: general-topology

$A$ is a compact subset of a metric space $(X, d)$.

(i) Show that the diameter of A is equal to $d(a, b)$ for some $a, b ∈ A$.

(ii) Given $x ∈ X$, show that $d(x, A) = d(x, a)$ for some $a ∈ A$.

(iii) If $B$ is a closed set and $A ∩ B = ∅$  then show that $d(A, B) > 0$.

I found first 2 trivial but couldn't write it rigorously. Am I missing something ?

I am stuck with part 3.

Comment: What are your (informal) arguments for 1. and 2.? For 3., consider $d(x,B)$ on $A$.

Comment: You can't say in the same sentence that you find something trivial but can't write it rigorously...

Comment: You'd better ask those questions separately.

Answer (score 0):

For Part 3, $d(A,B)=0$,

$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists a_n\in A,b_n\in B,$, s.t. $d(a_n,b_n)<\frac{1}{n}$. Since $A$ is compact, $\{a_n\}$ has subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$, s.t. $a_{n_k}\to a\in A$. Then $d(a,b_{n_k})\leq d(a,a_{n_k})+d(a_{n_k},b_{n_k})\leq d(a,a_{n_k})+\frac{1}{n_k}\to 0.$. Hence $b_{n_k}\to a$. Since $B$ is closed, $a\in B$. So $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$.